How many nodejs app instances can I run on this server
I have developed a nodejs api using express, mysql and prisma orm. Traffic will be very low. Around 100 requests an hour at peak usage. Most api calls involve a call to the db. Data returned will also be small. Maybe 10 to 20 rows at a time. The database will have around 30 tables, most of which will have very limited number of rows. Again, around 10 to 20 rows. There is however a transaction table that could over time become relatively big, lets say 3000 rows in a year.
Now, getting to my question. I have a dedicated server with the following specs:

Intel Xeon E5-2620 v3
6 cores/12 threads, 2.40 GHz – 3.20 GHz
64Gb ECC RAM
SSD drives for storage

Realistically, how many instances of the node app can I run (each instance will have its own seperate database on the same server)?

With that kind of traffic why would you need or want more than one? At a minimum, one per core, but with essentially zero traffic, more since it’s idle almost always. Since you have a server why not just run some load tests and find out?

There will be an instance per customer of my app. Not going the multitenant route as my app serves a different purpose.
